# iOS - Asynchronous clock running in background of app

Tags: ios, audio, core-audio

I'm doing an audio app where I need to manipulate audio buffers in real time for different sounds. I need a asynchronous clock running in the background that i can pull the time in various callbacks good to the millisecond for various audio manipulation purposes like the stop and start times of my audio playback, and when it records and stops recording.

I need it to be so such that the precision allows me to determine latency caused by the various processes and compensate for it in my code.

How would one implement such a clock in iOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the RemoteIO Audio Unit and requesting very short audio buffers from the Audio Session, then counting Remote callbacks and PCM samples within the callback buffer appears to be the most precise way to align audio with sub-millisecond resolution.  Anything else will be off by the amount of latency between callbacks.

You can also use the timer in the mach_time.h header for fairly precise monotonic time measurement, but this won't be sync'd to audio playback rate, nor account for various latencies between subsystems.

Comment: Hi hotpaw2, how do you "count" the remoteCallbacks and PCM samples? Could you post some pseudo code to illustrate?

Comment: One easy way to count callbacks is to increment a non-local counter within the callback.

Comment: And that is good enough? So I just increment the counter in every callback, that's it?

Comment: It helps to know the audio duration represented by each callback.  For uncompressed audio, usually proportional to the number of samples divided by the current sample rate.

Comment: Ah now that you phrase it in this way it makes sense, thanks!

Comment: Another question - how about time outside of the callbacks ? Surely some time is spent rendering animation and others? Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

If you have not already done so, I would definately advise you to look into the [AVFoundation Framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/00_Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188), and take use of [Core Audio](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/CoreAudioOverview/Introduction/Introduction.html). You can forget about the native NSTimer and NSDate options, considering your need of accuracy.

Comment: I am using core audio to manipulate the audio buffers, thanks